# Data Source of Google Trends

Tags: parsing, svg

I need to extract data used to build charts at Google Trends. I've heard that it gets possible by passing additional parameters in the url, but didn't find which ones.

Another idea was to look at the page source: http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=data&date=5%2F2007%201m&cmpt=q. But it's so messy, that I could not figure out anything.

Are there any ideas how to parse pages like that?

Please, help.

Comment: CSV extraction is not what I need. I don't need CSV, there is a download limit for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal Chrome Inspector detective work. Just keep clicking down the tree until you reach this element:

```
<path d="M0.5,31.29L26.1,25.62L51.7,19.95L77.3,29.4L102.9,84.21L128.5,
86.1L154.1,27.51L179.7,12.39L205.3,10.5L230.9,16.17L256.5,27.51L282.1,
86.1L307.7,86.1L333.3,23.73L358.9,14.28L384.5,16.17L410.1,19.95L435.7,
33.18L461.3,82.32L486.9,84.21L512.5,23.73L538.1,16.17L563.7,19.95L589.3,
21.84L614.9,35.07L640.5,89.88L666.1,89.88L691.7,52.08L717.3,
29.4L742.9,25.62L768.5,25.62" stroke="#1155cc" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path>
```

which actually draws the graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is another issue. After I parse the page through the script - google detects this and blocks me for a while. When I make multiple requests through the browser - everything is fine. Is there any way to emulate browser visit?